# integration and stochastic calculus

Tags: probability

Let $Z=\int_0^1 t dB_t$

Show that $Z=B_1-\int_0^1 B_tdt$ with an integration by parts.

I want to know if $Z=[tB_t]_0^1-\int_0^1 B_t dt$ is the formula of integration by parts

Thank you

Comment: That's right. (Be warned that this is not justified by the classical situation with integration by parts, however.)

Answer (score 0):

In stochastic integration, integration by parts referes to Ito's Lemma for the product of two stochastic process $X$ and $Y$ (eventually given by two deterministic functions $f, g$ of one or more stochastic variables) following the conditions of the lemma. So we have 
$$X_t Y_t = \int_0^t X_s ~ dY_s + \int_0^t Y_d ~ dX_s + \int_0^t d\langle X, Y\rangle_s  $$
We know that 
$$ d(t~ B_t) = t ~dB_t + B_t ~dt$$
which is the integration by part in differential form (informal notation) that the question referes to with 
$X_t = t $ (deterministic) and $Y_t = B_t$.

The 3rd therm (the quadratic variation or the crochet) is null since one of the functions is deterministic.

Now integrate it from 0 to 1 and you have the wanted result:

$$B_1 = Z + \int_0 ^1 B_t ~ dt $$